# htaccess to load assets from staging URL when file doesn't exist locally

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to load images from a staging site if they don't exist locally.
This is basically useful so I don't have to keep downloading all the images that the client uploads on the staging site. At the moment, what I have is working, but it's an all-or-nothing solution. So, all the images are loading remotely but I'd like htaccess to only load remote images if a local one doesn't exist.

Here's what I have:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local-site\.dev$

RewriteRule ^.*/uploads/(.*)$ http://remote-site.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,R=301]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local-site\.dev$
RewriteRule ^.*/(uploads/.*)$ http://remote-site.com/wp-content/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Here `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will make sure that this redirection happens only when image file doesn't exist locally.

Comment: Hello @anubhava is it possible to use dynamic url based on uri variable?

`RewriteRule ^.*/(uploads/.*)$ http://remote-site.com/wp-content/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`