# Use .htaccess to load files from remote site when they don't exist locally

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This SO article about [loading files from a remote site when they don't exist locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726578/htaccess-to-load-assets-from-staging-url-when-file-doesnt-exist-locally) provides .htaccess RewriteConds and RewriteRules to achieve the task.

I also want to use this on my WordPress site so I thought these instructions would be perfect for me, but they're not working. I'm using WordPress 3.9.1 running on MAMP PRO 2.0

I structure URLs for my local sites as; `local.domain.com` so I alter the patters from the original SO article to the following

```
# Use remote uploads when they don't exist locally
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*/(uploads/.*)$ http://domain.com/wp-content/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

The original SO article is not clear on where this .htaccess file should be placed. I tried it in the WordPress root directory, and /wp-content/uploads/ without success.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule in `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This worked for me anubhava, thanks.
So was the pattern I was matching in the original RewriteRule was wrong?

Comment: Yes `^.*/(uploads/.*)$` pattern cannot work from `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess`